# Create user input to search through a csv data frame - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, user-input

I am attempting to create a function that will run through my csv data frame and return only specific rows that match my desired parameters which in this case have to do with different percentages.

My question: How do I filter through my csv file by requesting different percentages using user input?

Here is a working chunk of code I currently have that filters my rows based on my column named "cost". It returns and exports all data that fall below 50%:

```
# all features file path
allfeat_file = "/Users/allfeat_file.csv"
# sends file into specific folder
DIR_out = '/Users/Output_Files/'
# exports output to a new csv file 
export_path = DIR_out +'allfeaturesbelow50%.csv'

#omit data [[50%]] and above & export output to new csv file
def omit_fifty(export_path):
    with open(allfeat_file, 'rb') as f:       
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
        for col_name in df.columns: 
            #cost = df["Cost"]
            below_fifty = df[df["Cost"] <= .50]
            below_fifty.to_csv(export_path)  
            print(below_fifty)
omit_fifty(export_path)
```

This works perfectly to filter out any data by cost that is over 50% and export it into a csv file, but now I want to be able to request whatever percentage I want. After that I can figure out how to export the data into it's own csv.

Any advise of what direction to take with this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to replace `.50` with `float(input())`? Also, unclear why you're looping over column names when you only access the Cost

Comment: use `value = input("Value:")` to ask user for value. Or use `sys.argv[1]` or module `argparse` to get this value as argument in command line - ie `python script.py .50`. In both situtions you get it as string so you have to use `float()` to convert string to float number.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, thank you. This was what I needed. I initially utilized multiple columns and might again in the future so I just figured I would leave it set up this way for now. Thanks again.